# Difference between submit & send

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs, headlinese

I'm working on an `order form` and have to add a "send" button to process the order. By clicking the button, the user is `sending/approving` the listed information of the order details.

My question is about the text for that button.

Should I use `Submit` or `Send`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For forms, be it physical or virtual, the commonly used word is "submit". "Send" is more widely used for emails, letter, etc.

In your case, "Submit" is preferred.